# SQL Server Last Day of the Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a varchar field that contains dates in this format:

```
YYYY-MM
```

I need to get the last day of the month and get the result in this format:

```
YYYYMMDD
```

For example:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(7) = '2019-01'
SELECT REPLACE(@date, '-', '') + RIGHT(@date, 2) AS date

My output is: 20190101
The output I am looking for is: 20190131
```

Comment: The first, and arguably biggest, issue is storing dates as varchar. Choosing the right datatype makes everything easier. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Answer (score 2):

Use `EOMONTH()` -- after converting the value:

```
select eomonth(convert(date, @date + '-01', 23))
```

If you want a string, use `FORMAT()` or `CONVERT()` to convert the value to a string.

Comment: Better to change convert(date, @ date + '-01')  to convert(date, @ date + '-01', 23). The format 23 means the string in yyyy-mm-dd format.   (The space between and @   and variable date is just for me to add the comment.)

Answer (score 0):

If eomonth is not available in your SQL Server version create a function;

```
    CREATE function [dbo].[LastDayofMonth](@Date datetime)
returns datetime
as
    begin
        return DATEADD(mi, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Date) + 1, 0))       
    end
```

Format the result;

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(7)
SET @Date = '2019-01'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DBO.LastDayofMonth(CAST(@Date+'-01' as DATETIME)),112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @date varchar(25)='2019-01'
Select format(EOMONTH(Cast(Concat(@date,'-01')  as date) ), 'yyyyMMdd')
```